# Add new element to json array using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, arrays, json

I have a json array

```
[{id:1,data:"test1"},{id:2,data:"test2"}]
```

I need to add a new element to each of the objects in the array based on the value of the "data" field. That is if the value of data is  "test1", the new field data should be  "test one type". The expected output is as below

```
[{id:1,data:"test1",type: "test1 Type"},{id:2,data:"test2",type: "test2 Type"}]
```

I tried with .push operation but it is adding new object to the array not updating the existing object. I am new to node NodeJs. Can you please help with this.

Comment: Spread operator might help you  `[...obj, { new: 'object'}]` Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: How to iterate over the  array and use spread. Could you help with an example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change properties of every item in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35879307/change-properties-of-every-item-in-an-array)

Answer (score -1):

u need to map add element via map function

```js
const data = [{id:1, data:"test1"},{id:2,data:"test2"}];
data.map(element => {
    element.type = `${element.data} type`
    return element;
});

console.log(data)
```